# Address Google Sheet address which would not be affected by viewer sorting (Using C# API)

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google sheet API (C#) to process data stored in a sheet.

My application processing is as follow:

```
 Input to the application is a list of data,
 Grab one item from the list
 Find the associated row in the sheet
 based on the sheet data, decide to process some external data (This may take several minutes).
 tag the row that data is processed.
```

In my solution, I read the spreadsheet to a list and then when I want to tag it, I use row number to find the cell to tag.

But if a viewer changes the order of data (for example by sorting or filtering) then the above method doesn't work.

Any better way to work with sheet that viewer sort or filtering doesn't affect it?

Comment: Use a dictionary with the key being something unique in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can make use of Google Sheets Developer Metadata

As specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata):

> Developer **metadata may be used to associate arbitrary data with
>   various parts of a spreadsheet and will remain associated at those
>   locations as they move around and the spreadsheet is edited**. For
>   example, if developer metadata is associated with row 5 and another
>   row is then subsequently inserted above row 5, that original metadata
>   will still be associated with the row it was first associated with
>   (what is now row 6).

Comment: That is exactly what I want! Is there any sample code (in C# or any other language) which shows how I can use this feature?

Comment: There is the general quickstart: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet, samples: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate and information about metadata https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata. On Stackoverflow you can find related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636262/google-sheets-api-v4-add-row-net/37663132#37663132 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226995/set-google-sheets-column-metadata-sheet-id-is-not-being-set-watch-a-spreadsh